# Unexpected output file type .html in target "main" (^^^^^^^^^^^^ File extension must be .js, .mjs, or .cjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, parceljs

i had installed parcel with version number "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0" and json i mentioned like this
when i try to run the command **npm start** i am error like this
i want to call index.html page but it is showing like File extension must be .js, .mjs, or .cjs
How can i solve this issue ?

````
"name": "receipe-book",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "you can get your favourite receipe here",
"main": "index.html",
"scripts": {
 "start": "parcel index.html",
 "build": "parcel build index.html"
},
"author": "Somu Nelavalli",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
 "parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0"
}```


Server running at http://localhost:1234
× Build failed.

@parcel/core: Unexpected output file type .html in target "main"

H:\Somu Pracatice\Javascript\complete-javascript-course-master\complete-javascript-course-master\18-forkify\starter\package.json:5:11
 4 |   "description": "you can get your favourite receipe here",
> 5 |   "main": "index.html",
>   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ File extension must be .js, .mjs, or .cjs
 6 |   "scripts": {
 7 |     "start": "parcel index.html",

The "main" field is meant for libraries. If you meant to output a .html file, either remove the "main" field or choose a different target name.

Thanks in Advance
````

Answer (score 4):

The source of that error is the `"main": "index.html"` field in your `package.json`. According to [the documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/#project-setup), this field is intended to be used by library projects (e.g. npm packages that are consumed by others) - it tells parcel to output a commonjs JavaScript bundle at that location, which doesn't make sense for an html file.

Since it doesn't appear that you are developing a library, you can simply remove `"main": "index.html"`, and it should work fine ([see migration docs](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#package.json%23main)).

To specify the ouput directory for non-library projects, use the `--dist-dir` cli parameter instead ([see docs](https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters)).

Comment: How would you specify the output directory in that case?

Comment: Use the `--dist-dir` cli parameter - see: https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters

Answer (score 2):

Rename `main` to `default` in the package.json file.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "default": "dist/index.html"
}
```